# Do we need a new tag "acceptance-phase"/"customer-acceptance-phase" for all acceptance-phase issues?

Tags: discussion, tags

I suggest we need a new tag [acceptance-phase](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acceptance-phase)/[customer-acceptance-phase](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customer-acceptance-phase).
There are several questions on the topic of employees (sometimes contractors) **completing (or believing they've completed) a (technical) deliverable yet having the customer claim it had missing features/ bugs/ performance issues, demand rework or adding(/removing) features, port it to platform Y, etc. Often unpaid. Often there was no clear written SOW**. And/or it was never defined whether the contractor gets paid for any of this, who is responsible for acceptance testing, which specific people at the customer get to define acceptance, how disputes are resolved. It gets even more complicated when there are multiple companies/contractor firms/customers/third-parties/compliance burdens involved.

Notes: No it's not a legal question. **The concept is not software specific, it arises in many jobs: engineering, medical, legal etc.** It's not always contractors, sometimes it's about managing/dealing with contractors or accepting their deliverable(s), or the wider impact on QA or schedule.

These questions are related, but you can't tell that because the terms used are different every time, and most of the OPs haven't even heard the term "(customer) acceptance phase" or have a clause covering getting paid for it in their contract, "acceptance criteria", Statement-of-Work. Look for "finished", "final", "deliverable", "handoff", "rework" etc.

- [What to do when your line manager has a very different vision of the deliverable?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/77093/what-to-do-when-your-line-manager-has-a-very-different-vision-of-the-deliverable?s=1|25.2000)
- [Customer told me to stay out of discussion regarding status of my delivered product](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/119016/customer-told-me-to-stay-out-of-discussion-regarding-status-of-my-delivered-prod)
- [Frustration with code supplied by a third-party company](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/80244/frustration-with-code-supplied-by-a-third-party-company)
- [Manager causing scope creep [closed]](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/56994/manager-causing-scope-creep)
- [As a freelancer, what exactly is considered project work?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/95094/as-a-freelancer-what-exactly-is-considered-project-work)
- acceptance phase, but not about software: [Progress blockage due to political tensions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/58755/progress-blockage-due-to-political-tensions)
- marginal [Product delivered quite rough, and coworker complaining on social network site when in QA](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/95886/product-delivered-quite-rough-and-coworker-complaining-on-social-network-site-w)
- marginal [Colleague keeps on making mistakes, how to help him?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/74155/colleague-keeps-on-making-mistakes-how-to-help-him)
- marginal [State in the contract that software developer delivers only binary code not source code? [closed]](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/34750/state-in-the-contract-that-software-developer-delivers-only-binary-code-not-sour)
- [Employer changed duties - possible bait and switch?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/83696/employer-changed-duties-possible-bait-and-switch/83716#83716)
- ...many others, please add here...

**Note: this tag has nothing whatsoever to do with "job offer acceptance", 
 offer letters, offer deadlines, retractions, recruiters etc.,** and since those are the more common usage of the term "acceptance" on WP, we probably also need a [offer-acceptance](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offer-acceptance) to avoid confusion.

Comment: Too many tags already. We don't need software-specific tags here.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: **it's not software specific**. It occurs in many jobs: engineering, medical, legal. Nowhere above does it say software-specific.

Comment: We have about 500 tags. I don't see the point.

Comment: I agree with @JoeStrazzere our tags are too many and messy as it is.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, MisterPositive: irrelevant. This has nothing to do with the other tags. If you see the need for a tag cleanup thread, please start one. It's not a reason to block unrelated improvements in the meantime.

Comment: Not taking a stand for or against this, but if we really have 500 tags, shouldn't there be some that need burninating?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that this is helpful, and I think that it would simply add confusion.

From the [tag page](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/tags)

> Using the right tags makes it easier for others to find and answer your question

You've already admitted yourself that:

> These questions are related, but you can't tell that because the terms used are different every time, and most of the OPs haven't even heard the term "(customer) acceptance phase"

So, most OPs won't add this tag to their question if they're unaware of the term.  To many people, "acceptance-phase" would be linked to an offer acceptance, and that's how this tag will (inappropriately) be used in most cases (and there's already a [job-acceptance](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-acceptance) tag for that purpose).

Tags are there to be used for search and categorization.  I can see your point that it would bring those kinds of questions together, but you have a larger task of educating people about that term.  It's likely that you're the only person who would really engage and use this.

We prefer tags to be clear, unambiguous, and intuitive in their wording, so much so that the tag description won't need to be used to understand it.

And as noted, we already have a lot of tags.

Comment: *"So, most OPs won't add this tag to their question if they're unaware of the term"* That's how some tags get rolling. So we kickstart the use of the tag by applying it. (I already did by compiling that list). Then people become aware of the term. *"You have a larger task of educating people about that term. It's likely that you're the only person who would really engage and use this."* So fine. Then others learn. And argument-by-association/apathy of the community isn't a reason to not make an improvement. *"Tags are there to be used for search and categorization."* Then it's justified.

Comment: *"We prefer tags to be clear, unambiguous, and intuitive in their wording, so much so that the tag description won't need to be used to understand it."* So do I, "prefer" is an aspiration not a hard requirement. As time goes by, people will add specialized terms where some users need to read the tag description (that's not an argument for accepting every tag). Clearly 90+% of WP users haven't heard the term "acceptance phase". Yet many users are complaining about not getting paid, or milestones not being hit, etc. for this reason.

Comment: *"as noted, we already have a lot of tags"* But that's got nothing to do with me, or this proposal. Take it up with the creators of sparsely-used, possibly unnecessary tags like [tag:interim-report]. Or  the German term [tag:zeugnis], which is apparently legit but almost everyone will need to read the tag definition. Or the undefined bullshit tag [tag:workplace-rhythm] which seems to be misused. And what about the use of the not-really-defined [tag:process]. And others. I support any other proposals to improve/refine/cull tags as needed. But don't drag any of that in here.

Comment: Oh and *"Using the right tags makes it easier for others to find and answer your question"* is not to be misconstrued as *"Don't use the right tags even if they are the most appropriate tags, when their names may not be widely-known"*.